# Workflow 2010 - Set Email from to users email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I am looking to find out if there is a way I can override the system email which is the 'From field' and Reply address to all emails sent through out SharePoint 2013 system using 2010 Workflows.

I have a form which sends straight to a helpdesk which auto responds to the user assigning a work number. The system email address breaks this process. I would like to replace the system email (From email field) with the Email Current Item: Created By.

Has anyone had success here or have an insight as to whether this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**No**. This is not possible.

You can't specify the FROM address for email messages when you use the `Send an email` option from a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow action.

**Workarounds**:

1. As there is no OOTB solution to make it, you will need to use a custom activity like explained here:

   [How to Change From Address of SharePoint Designer workflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/4349bdfd-75c0-46c9-83a7-45471bf85ecc/how-to-change-from-address-of-sharepoint-designer-workflow).
2. Use SharePoint designer workflow 2013 and **Call HTTP Web Service** like explained here:

   [Workaround - Specify the FROM address for email messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2014/10/24/you-cant-specify-the-from-address-for-email-messages-when-you-use-the-send-an-email-option-from-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-action/).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I'm not sure if either solution will work for our setup. The second one certainly won't as we are running SP 2010 workflows. I will need to check out the first solution as this site is now archived - see if its viable. Thanks again

Comment: Welcome. Try and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Have you tried this? is it working for you??

Comment: unfortunately not - we did not activate SP 2013 workflows with this build so we are running off a 2010 platform.